# Send proactive messages to MS Teams from PHP

Tags: php, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have an PHP application that should send proactive messages to individual MS Teams users and send notifications to Teams channel as well. I spent a lot of time reading docs
but totally got stack with one-way notification bot for MS Teams.

What done:
I created app with bot by App Studio and register it at botframework. So now I can install it to my Teams.

My questions:
Is is possible to send proactive messages with PHP (without SDK, Rest API) and how create that kind of bot? I can get an token from Rest API but how to identify team and start proactive conversation?

Comment: I am not fully into that topic, but you may create webhooks to do so.

Comment: It is not that I need. I need to send proactive messages to user from php.

Comment: But as far as I know you can setup a [webhook/connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using) exactly doing that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a troublesome topic for exactly this reason - the docs explain how to *Send* the message, but not that there are *critical* variables you need, and that you *need to have them already*, for instance "ServiceUrl" and "ConversationId". They are unique to every user (for 1-1 chat) or for every conversation. You can get these any time the user calls your bot (they are on the "Activity" object), but also right as your app is installed by the user - there is a "ConversationUpdate" event call that is sent, that contains them too. You then need to store them your side (e.g. in a database), for later use in sending the *actual* 'proactive message'.

Hopefully that gives you what you need, but if anything is still unclear let me know in the "comments"

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Do not sure that I understand what is "app is installed by the user".

Probably my post above is not entirely accurate, here is a full description what I need:
I have an PHP webservice with users.   
  
When some events occurs at the PHP webservice:
 1. Send notification to user (I have only email so find user at MS Teams by email).
 2. Send notification to special predefined channel.
In my flow MS Teams users do not interact with my Bot and I need somehow initiate notification. So I need to somehow initiate install MS Team app from PHP webservice once (OUATH?)

Comment: let me try explain better. If you only want to send messages to a channel, then the incoming webhook is fine. If you want to send to both users directly (i.e. "1-1") as well as to Channels, then you need to create a bot. When a user adds the bot to the channel, your bot will receive the "ConversationUpdate" event, and it can save certain details out of there, to send the proactive message later. For the 1-1 proactive messaging to work, *each* of the users must also install the bot themselves, as a personal app. Each of those installation will also fire it's own "ConversationUpdate" event

Comment: does that explain better?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow It took me a week to figure all this out, I started building a MS Team app using REST API 2 weeks back and I am still building it. What you have written is something I was able to figure out and now just working on it.
Though there is 1 thing I have not been able to find is that -> Is there a Bot API to create a channel and add members to it?

Comment: It's quite a learning curve so great that you're making progress. Unfortunately you can't modify the Team itself through the Bot Framework, but these things are all possible using the Graph (so your bot could even be the thing that calls the Graph, but it would need authorisation to do that)

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Thank you for this, this is exactly what I thought. Thank you for clearing this.

Comment: sure, glad to help. Please be sure to upvote or mark as answer, so others with a similar issue can see that this was helpful

Comment: Thanks @HiltonGiesenow!
So to send proactive messages to channel and 1+1 there is only one way:
Set Messaging endpoint for bot and receive Conversation object?
Will I get any response when Bot added to Team ([Team members added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=json#team-members-added)) or  is it means "Bot added to the channel"?
My idea is get info about user from initial event and then install Bot using Graph API. What you think?

Comment: great, thanks and good luck with your Teams project

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow could you please add your thoughts about my comment above. My idea is add Event object when bot added to team and then search users at team and install app with Graph API. But not sure that will get response Event after App installed to Team.

Comment: sorry Dmitry, I missed your message somehow. It's a good question about "channel" events - I'm not -totally- sure if your bot will get notified if it's added to multiple channels in the -same- team. It's easy enough to test, and I think that actually it -would- because a channel results in a unique converstationID.

Comment: Separately, you certainly could do what you're proposing - auto-install, using graph, for each user in the channel - you'd just need the correct permissions. I think that particular endpoint is "beta" only though, so just be aware of the risk around that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-add-teamsappinstallation?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks, @HiltonGiesenow for your help! I think there is another way: Regarding [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#obtain-necessary-user-information) Bot can create conversation and then send a message. But for that action bot needs UID and tenantId. Do you know how to get that fields without installing  bot to any channels?